# PHP Regex to remove HTML-Tag

Tags: php, regex

I am looking for a way to search a string in PHP and remove `"<pre"`, `"</pre>"` and everything, that is in between.

**Example:**

```
$string = 'Hello, I am a little text. <pre class="foo">This should be deleted.</pre> This is fine again.';
// Some magic function
$newString = 'Hello, I am a little text.  This is fine again.';
```

Is there any way to do it? If I use `strip_tags()`, only the tags will be removed, but now the content inside of the tags.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's just a small string, I don't recommend it but regex would be alright here.

```
$newString = preg_replace('~<pre[^>]*>[^<]*</pre>~', '', $str);
```

However, I always use [**DOM**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) when dealing with HTML/XML.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('pre') as $tag) {
   $tag->parentNode->removeChild($tag);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd use @hwnd's parsing example below (or above), that's a lot safer than using regex.

You could use something like this:

```
/<(.*?)(\h*).*?>(.*?)<\/\1>/
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/cN9rL4/3

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/415470

```
echo preg_replace('/<(.*?)(\h*).*?>(.*?)<\/\1>/s', '', 'Hello, I am a little text. <pre class="foo">This should be deleted.</pre> This is fine again.');
```

Output:

> Hello, I am a little text.  This is fine again.

Edit: added `s` modifier in case the content exceeds one line, demo of failure https://regex101.com/r/cN9rL4/2.

Also note this isn't specific to `pre` this will replace any elements it encounters that close.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!